# How to change object's Y projection axis and color via C# rather than XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, xaml, storyboard

I'm working on a Silverlight project where I will be 'flipping' rectangles by rotating them on the Y projection axis. I will also change to color in the middle of the animation so that it looks like the back side of the rectangle is a different color. I can do this in XAML no problem however I need to do this via code because I want to dynamically flip different rectangles. I don't want to have to create an animation for each rectangle on the grid. Here's what my XAML looks like:

```
<Storyboard x:Name="Flip1">
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Projection).(PlaneProjection.RotationY)" Storyboard.TargetName="rectangle">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="-90"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.6" Value="-90"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="0"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="rectangle">
                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="Blue"/>
                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.6" Value="Red"/>
            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
```

I've created storyboards from code several times however this one is leaving me a bit stumped with the EasingDoubleKeyFrames. Any ideas how to go about doing this?

Comment: As I know, every tag in xaml represents its `class`. Nested elements are `KeyFrames` - you need to add items to this collection. I don't see the problem at all...

Answer (score 1):

This should be the translation of the first animation:

```
var anim = new DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames();
anim.KeyFrames.Add(new EasingDoubleKeyFrame() { KeyTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0), Value = 0 });
anim.KeyFrames.Add(new EasingDoubleKeyFrame() { KeyTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5), Value = -90 });
anim.KeyFrames.Add(new EasingDoubleKeyFrame() { KeyTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.6), Value = -90 });
anim.KeyFrames.Add(new EasingDoubleKeyFrame() { KeyTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), Value = 0 });
Storyboard.SetTarget(anim, rectangle);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(anim, new PropertyPath("Projection.RotationY"));
```

When using `Storyboards` you further need to register the target in a namescope, i recommend reading the whole reference of the [`Storyboard`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.storyboard.aspx) class.

Comment: Hello H.B. Maybe I just don't know what I'm doing here. This is what I tried. No errors but no results either...

Comment: var anim = new DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames();
anim.KeyFrames.Add(new EasingDoubleKeyFrame() { KeyTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0), Value = 0 });
anim.KeyFrames.Add(new EasingDoubleKeyFrame() { KeyTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5), Value = -90 });
anim.KeyFrames.Add(new EasingDoubleKeyFrame() { KeyTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.6), Value = -90 });
anim.KeyFrames.Add(new EasingDoubleKeyFrame() { KeyTime =

Comment: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), Value = 0 });
Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();
sb.Children.Add(anim);
Storyboard.SetTarget(anim, Rec1);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(anim, new PropertyPath("Projection.RotationY"));
Rec1.MouseEnter += (object sended, MouseEventArgs f) => sb.Begin();

Comment: Yes, it works in XAML with no issues. The XAML only took me a few minutes to complete. Doing this in code is proving to be a more complicated endeavor.

Comment: Can you try changing your PropertyPath to "(UIElement.Projection).(PlaneProjection.RotationY)" and see what happens?