# DoubleAnimation, how do I perform an action at a certain value?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I have a Rectangle that I am using PlaneProjection to spin on its Y axis.  The Range is set from 0 to 360 and it works fine.  What I would like to do however is change the fill color once the value reaches a certain point, 180 and then at 360 in this case.  I can't see to find a way to "watch" this property and the animation only exposes a Completed event.

The only possible way I can think of to do this is setup 2 animations, 1 from 0 to 180 and another from 180 to 360, and then change the color back and forth in between.  This method feels a little kludgy to me though and I'm not sure how to get the two animations to fire continuously in a loop.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7102506/how-to-change-objects-y-projection-axis-and-color-via-c-sharp-rather-than-xaml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7102506/how-to-change-objects-y-projection-axis-and-color-via-c-sharp-rather-than-xaml)

Comment: Quite right, I didn't come across that when I was searching.  I'm not a 100% sure I understand how hes accomplishing the color change unless hes just just timing it.  I'll explore this further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to bind another (custom?) property to the rotation property on the PlaneProjection and in the property change handler change the fill color.

Another option is to use a ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames with DiscreteColorKeyFrame and set the color of the SolidColorBrush used for your Fill at the time when the value of the rotation reaches the desired value. Note that your value will be 180 typically in half the time you set your animation duration to unless you use something like DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames or use easing functions.

Then you could also bind the Fill property to the rotation property on the PlaneProjection with a converter that chooses the correct color.

Comment: Thanks!  I've gotten it close by adding the ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames to the storyboard.  I've gotten it close but it will take some work to get the timing right.  I changed the spin to use duration and set it to 3 seconds.  Then I set the color animation to fire at 1.5 and 3.  The color changes but the timing is definitely off.  I'll keep tweaking it, I just hope the spin rate is constant from device to device.

Comment: If these animations are part of the same storyboard then they are controlled by the same timer and will never get out of sync. You should use Blend to get the timing right. You can also make it easier by setting SpeedRatio to something lower than 1 on the Storyboard to see it in slow motion.